# What is the difference between .elf and .bin file?

Tags: linux, qemu

I was working with hardware emulation on QEMU (bare metal) and I ran the command.

1. arm-none-eabi-gdb test.elf
2. qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel test.bin

The .c files are different but in both cases simple code is run on QEMU. What is the difference between these two files and commands?

Comment: Covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427011/what-is-the-difference-between-elf-files-and-bin-files

Comment: You found the difference yourself: With ELF you don't need to specify so much and can save on the drudgery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for the .bin and .elf file difference on stack overflow itself.

Basically, bin file is purely, binary files with bits and bytes which go and locate at the particular address. Where as the elf file has lot more information such as symbol tables,debug information etc. 
[Check this link for detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427011/what-is-the-difference-between-elf-files-and-bin-files)